# Media source extensions: How to remove a sourcebuffer buffered range

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, media-source

```
 console.log (sourceBuffer.buffered.length) //3
 sourceBuffer.remove(0); 
         //TypeError: Failed to execute 'remove' on 'SourceBuffer': required,    
         // 2 arguments but only 1 present.
```

Does `sourceBuffer.remove()` remove a buffered range or the entire sourceBuffer?

If so what are the two expected arguments?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the [Media Source Extensions docs found here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html#methods-1)? There is a section _("3.2 Methods")_ that describes a remove() function; the function evidently takes start and end numerical _(double)_ parameters... does this help at all?

Answer (score 1):

The `remove` method removes a buffered time range. The function takes two arguments, a start time and an end time. Both the start time and end time are in seconds. An error will be emitted if you call `remove` while the `updating` property of the source buffer is `true`. An `updateend` event will be emitted when the `remove` operation is completed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/remove